# Can't figure out the syntax for this AR query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax

I'm trying to run this query:

```
Result.where('link = #{site}').present?
```

where `site` is a string. However the problem with the code above is that because of the single quotes, `site` will not be interpolated.

If i try

```
Result.where("link = #{site}").present?
```

I get a syntax error.

How can I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be hacked next day you use it. It has severe [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issue.

What you have to do is this:

```
Result.where(:link => site)
```

Or if you need something other than equality then this syntax is better:

```
    Result.where('link <> ?', site)
```

You can read more [here](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface).

Comment: Better than what I just said. Facepalm moment :)

Answer (score -1):

If my memory serves I think you can double up the quotes:

```
Result.where('"link = #{site}"').present?
```